# Set an active class on top level menu item when on sub-menu item page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried quite a few ways and maybe I'm just missing something simple. I'm trying to see the top level menu item as .top_active when on a sub-menu item page that corresponds to that top level menu item.

```
var has_active_class = $('#sub_menu_set_active').hasClass('active');

if(has_active_class == true) {
    $('.found_top_level').addClass('top_active');
} else {
    $('.found_top_level').addClass('');
}
```

Just some background on what you see here other than my failed attempt at making this work. #sub_menu_set_active is an id that is set on an 'a' tag via PHP in a foreach loop when conditions are met during the json_decode that is also setting an 'active' class on that particular sub-menu item depending on the page you are currently viewing.

What I'm getting is .found_top_level is being applied to every 'a' tag that has a sub-menu that is generated and not the particular top level menu item that associates with the sub-menu page being viewed.

If anything else is needed code wise please let me know.

**Adding the generated HTML below...**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle found_top_level top_active" href="#" id="menu-200" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About</a>

<ul id="top_level_menu_item" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-arrow dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-xl-left" aria-labelledby="menu-200">

<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a id="sub_menu_set_active" class="dropdown-item active" href="page/track-info">Track Info</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/directions">Directions</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/rules">Rules</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/history">History</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.found_top_level')` will select every element with the class "found_top_level".

If you want the one with your active submenu, use the submenu element you already have selected:

```js
var has_active_class = $('#sub_menu_set_active').hasClass('active');

$('#sub_menu_set_active').closest('.dropdown-menu').prev('.found_top_level').toggleClass('top_active', has_active_class);
```

```css
.active { background-color: lime; }
.top_active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle found_top_level top_active" href="#" id="menu-200" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About</a>

  <ul id="top_level_menu_item" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-arrow dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-xl-left" aria-labelledby="menu-200">

    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a id="sub_menu_set_active" class="dropdown-item active" href="page/track-info">Track Info</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/directions">Directions</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/rules">Rules</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/history">History</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

Or, select it based off of the presence of the active class on the submenu.

```js
var has_active_class = $('#sub_menu_set_active').hasClass('active');

$('.dropdown-menu:has(.dropdown-item.active) ~ .found_top_level').toggleClass('top_active', has_active_class);
```

```css
.active { background-color: lime; }
.top_active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle found_top_level top_active" href="#" id="menu-200" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About</a>

  <ul id="top_level_menu_item" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-arrow dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-xl-left" aria-labelledby="menu-200">

    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a id="sub_menu_set_active" class="dropdown-item active" href="page/track-info">Track Info</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/directions">Directions</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/rules">Rules</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item " href="page/history">History</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you @Heretic Monkey that worked perfectly. I really appreciate the help.